# How to install Lattice Diamond 3.4 on ubuntu 14?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, gnome, software-installation

I am having a problem regarding the installation of Lattice diamond 3.4 software on Ubuntu. I downloaded the `rpm` file and converted into `deb` file using `alien`. Then tried to unpack it using command

```
sudo dpkg -i <filename>
```

The file started unpacking but at the end it showed

```
Extracting compressed files...
```

That's it.. I cant see any icon of the software or anything. I am in urgent need. Thank you

Comment: I need an account? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
alien --scripts rpmfile.rpm

The license file also checks for network card on eth0 only. So if your
network card is called something else, then the license file does not work.